# Android: Creating a Function with a file path

Tags: android, function

I'm trying to create a function that points to a sound file in my R.raw.xxxx folder. I can't figure out how to set the path to the file.

```
public void setsounds(Button buttonname, int fileId) {

        buttonname.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                sound = (R.raw.fileID); //this is where R.raw.fileId should go
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.raw.fileID` is just an id and more precisely an integer.
To get the actual resource, do something like that from your activity:

```
InoutStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fileID);
```

Comment: at what point does this error happen? how fo you define the file ID?